# SSIS ADO.NET Destination table using variable?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SSDT and working on a simple SSIS package.

The Control flow:
1. A Foreach Loop Container and seek a folder exist a "importdata{*}.csv" file or not.
2. If found, a script task will set variables:
  - User::FullPath = (e.g C:\importdata{*}.csv)
  - User::varFileNameNoExt = (importdata{*}) without extension.
The {*} is possible in "toy","game","food". 
3. Go to dataflow

The Data Flow:
1. Flat File Source with a flat file connection, the connection string is varible and mapped connection string expression.
2.ADO.NET Destination , insert data.

[image][image]

My question is how can i set the ADO.NET Destination [TableOrViewName] Property in variable?
Assume the table : importdatatoy,importdatagame and importdatafood is created on SQL Server.

I try to set as **"dbo"."[User::varFileNameNoExt]"** ,but it cannot resolve the table name on runtime.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADO.NET Destination [TableOrViewName]  parametrization can be done at Data flow level. In data flow properties, you can specify "ADO.NET Destination [TableOrViewName]".

Also specify the quotes while assigning value to variable
Eg: varFileNameNoExt = "dbo"."tableName"

But first you will need to create mapping with an existent table.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the [ADO.NET Destination].[TableOrViewName]  Expression is locate on Data flow Task itself, but not ADO.NET Destination Component.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your error message?  I'm thinking you won't be able to combine static text and a variable like that inside of the TableOrViewName field.  Instead do the combination in a new [User::varTableName] SSIS variable and use the Advanced Properties Expression editor to set the TableOrViewName to this new SSIS variable.  Have a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/725a5e73-8dec-4202-b2b6-b86810f9e485/passing-dynamic-table-name-in-ado-net-destination?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

Comment: Thanks, I should not put the Static text (dbo) prepend with table variable ([User::varFileNameNoExt]) to the TableOrViewName directly.
The correct way is locate to the right-bottom property input box on visual studio, open the Data Flow Component's expression, and map the variable with [ADO.NET Destination].[TableOrViewName].

It is  very strange the expression above is classified as to belong Data Flow Task. but not  ADO.NET Destination Component.